# What is intrinsic gravitational entropy?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, cosmology, entropy

What is [intrinsic gravitational entropy](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=intrinsic+gravitational+entropy)? Does it have to do with dark matter or coarse graining in the universe? Is it unique to general relativity, or there are predictions from quantum mechanics as well? Please explain in detail.

Comment: Can you provide a reference. The only use of the term I can find is [in a paper by Lee Smolin](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00761902).

Comment: @John Rennie,I read about it in "nature of space and time" by hawking and penrose. They haven't explained what it is, they've just cited it as a reason for the uniqueness of gravitational field.

Comment: @JohnRennie how about something like this http://www.researchgate.net/publication/225845616_On_the_intrinsic_entropy_of_the_gravitational_field http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF00761902

Comment: @GRocks: Entropy and gravitation can be considered opposite phenomena. Entropy works toward greater freedom of particles (they naturally try to move away from each other due to entropy), while gravity works toward restricting their freedom (bringing them together). Now, what Hawking meant by gravitational entropy? All that comes to mind might be simply entropy restricted by gravitation. Which is always the case (but this time Hawking said that).

Comment: @bright magnus, Thanx...i got what you said..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement is by Hawking. Assuming I understand him correctly he means that there is an entropy associated with gravitational fields that is quite separate from any any entropy associated with matter or radiation. In other words this entropy is intrinsic to the gravitational field and will always be present regardless of the arrangement of matter and energy.

The obvious example of this is the entropy associated with a black hole. This entropy depends only on the area of the event horizon and not on whatever matter fell into the black hole.

Comment: Thanks @John Rennie, I seem to understand it a bit now. can an analogy be drawn to dark matter or dark energy, because these are also quite unique features of spacetime independent of the inhomogeneities, and are also associated with gravitational field ?

Comment: @GRrocks: I don't think there is a useful analogy. Dark matter is just matter like baryonic matter, it's just made from weakly interacting particles. The nature of dark energy is unknown.

Comment: So we cannot assume dark energy and dark matter as a measure of the entropy of spacetime itself?I think we should, as like Hawking wrote, this does not seem to be a result of coarse graining(as there is no macroscopic difference in {dark}matter distribution in vacuum-spacetime), as matter gets accumulated only in regions like galaxies etc, otherwise, it is just dark matter, and it does have a gravitational effect, and so must have an entropy associated with it. And (if we ignore quantum fluctuations), dark matter is the only thing that can lead to such independant and intrinsic entropy. wrong?

Comment: @GRrocks: wrong. The entropy associated with the gravitational field is just a function of the field and would be unchanged in dark matter and energy didn't exist.